# How can I invert spelling proposals on iOS?

Tags: ios, auto-complete, spelling

Is there a way to invert the behavior of the spelling proposal ?

By "invert" I mean :

- Don't change what I have typed if I don't do anything special

**AND**

- Select the proposal if I tap on it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable "Auto-Correction" under `Settings > General > Keyboard`.

The check spelling will still be on and taping on the word detected as wrong will prompt you the corrections.